# Calculating average time to complete a function in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am running a simple sort 1000 times and trying to get the average time it takes to complete (and then compare to another sort) based on a user defined array length. My problem is that when i try to get the time it is always 0. I haven't coded in a while and am not seeing my error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TimingExpBubble2 {
    public static long average(long[] arr){
        int sum = 0; 

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
            sum += arr[i]; 

        return sum / arr.length; 
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter array length: ");
        int x = reader.nextInt();
        long[] time = new long[1000];
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int[] arr = new int[x];
            for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                arr[j] = (int) (Math.random() * 5000);
            }
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int l = 0; l < arr.length - 1; l++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < arr.length - i; j++) {
                    if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
                        int temp = arr[j - 1];
                        arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            reader.close();
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            time[i] = (end - start);
        }
        System.out.println("Average time in Miliseconds: " + average(time));
    }

}
'''
```

Comment: Use System.nanoTime()

Comment: In most cases (of my testing) the sort to `0` milliseconds,  Over an array of 10 elements.  This tended to produce a very small value (1-3 milliseconds) over 1000 iterations, so the result, on average was `0.003` milliseconds (for example) - instead of using a `long` for your result, you will need to use a `double` - which will require you to change one of divisible values to a `double` as well

Comment: I might be tempted to use the `java.time` API and it's `Duration` support - but doing so might introduce additional overhead :/

Comment: Changing it to a double or using nano both work. Thank you for the input

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `System.nanoTime()` instead `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: Using nano also works. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with help from a friend. 
i needed to put my time variables and measurements as a double since the amounts where so small and it helped to just using a running variable rather than an array
'''

```
time = time + (end - start);
        }
        System.out.println("Average time in Miliseconds: " + (time / 1000));
```

'''